# Image Print option in html

Tags: javascript, php

I have 6 images in PHP page.
Below each image there is button named print.

Now how to give command in `PHP` or `Javascript` to the button so that when it is clicked print window is there with only respective image (not whole HTML)

**My button:**

`<button type='print'>Print<\button>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ImagetoPrint(source) {
    return "<html><head><script>function step1(){\n" +
            "setTimeout('step2()', 10);}\n" +
            "function step2(){window.print();window.close()}\n" +
            "</scri" + "pt></head><body onload='step1()'>\n" +
            "<img src='" + source + "' /></body></html>";
}
function PrintImage(source) {
    Pagelink = "about:blank";
    var pwa = window.open(Pagelink, "_new");
    pwa.document.open();
    pwa.document.write(ImagetoPrint(source));
    pwa.document.close();
}
<a href="#" onclick="PrintImage('YOUR_IMAGE_PATH_HERE.JPG'); return false;">PRINT</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS libraries like

http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/

```
$('img#some_id').printElement();
```